# Can I use a Rails application without AR, but with GraphQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I mean Rails application that would receive data from GraphQL (another site) and would not have its own database.

For example, is it possible to use the models somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can use Rails without AR. You can also use most of the features of rails models (validations, attribute assignment, etc.) by including ActiveModel::Model. But there is no ORM for GraphQL which is equivalent to AR - just a basic adapter.

Comment: But "component shopping" questions are off topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Hmm, [GraphQL Ruby](http://graphql-ruby.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

`rails new --skip-active-record` to create a new app without active record

Then follow [graph ql](http://graphql-ruby.org/) installation:

Add `gem 'graphql'` to your Gemfile, run `bundle install`, then:

```
rails generate graphql:install
```

Comment: The fact that I can create a Rails application without AR - I knew :) But most of all I'm interested in the part about GraphQL. I meant, they say, is there a ready solution? Or any text about it?